# Cant get regex to limit based on a number range

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having issues basically setting up a regex to match a particular format. Here is the desired format:

**Monday**(any day of week) **1-7** (month - day) **1:00** (time (12 hour format))(multiple occurrences allowed but has to match this pattern) **inferno/cache/mirage** (multiple occurrences allowed)

So far I have most of it done, but I've looked up several SO's and other websites that tell me how to regex a number range. The part I am having issues with is the time part. I had one regex that allowed 1:00, but I couldn't figure out how to also allow just a number like 1 or 2 and no `:00` at the end. So I wanted to understand this a bit more so I decided to make it simpler for now and just do numbers 1-12.

Here is my current pattern:

```
const scrimFormatPattern = /(((mon|fri|sun)(day)?|tue(sday)?|wed(nesday)?|thu(rsday)?|sat(urday)?)+ ((0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]))+ ([1-9]|1[012])+ .*((inferno)|(nuke)|(mirage)|(dust2)|(train)|(overpass)|(cache)|\/))/gims
```

Everything will work but the time part. Even this simple one, which the time taken out is just `([1-9]|1[012])`, it does not fail when I put in 13.

**EDIT** Yes I know I have a number range for the date part, I tried to take that logic and use it with the time but it still doesn't work.

**EDIT 2** here is the code I am using to check for a match, it's a discord bot so `msg.content` is just a string that a user typed in discord.

```
let result = msg.content.match(scrimFormatPattern)
```

**EDIT 3** here is a sample of input that did not fail this pattern `wed 1-9 13 inferno`

**EDIT 4** I think I have in a good spot, but can't seem the regex to pick up on multiple entries, here's the latest pattern:

`const scrimFormatPattern = /(((mon|fri|sun)(day)?|tue(sday)?|wed(nesday)?|thu(rsday)?|sat(urday)?)+ ((0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]))+ ((1[012])(:|| )(00|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9]|5[0-9])? ?[aApP]m|(1[012])(:|| )(00|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9]|5[0-9])?)+ ((inferno)|(nuke)|(mirage)|(dust2)|(train)|(overpass)|(cache)|\/))/gims`

if you do

`wed 1-9 13:00 inferno`

it will fail (as it should)

but if you do

`wed 1-9 12 13:00 inferno`

it will pass (as it shouldn't)

Comment: Try this for your time match `(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):?([0-5]?[0-9])?` ...

Comment: @tink only 12 hour

Comment: So how do you deal w/ morning/afternoon?

Comment: @tink AM/PM which I have added in my update

Comment: Then update your update again, I still see many 13s ...

Comment: @tink huh? 13 is invalid and should fail, which i outlined in my question.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/rr3QKk/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your regex was over complicated try this:

```
((mon|fri|sun)(day)?|tue(sday)?|wed(nesday)?|thu(rsday)?|sat(urday)?) (0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-([0-2]?[1-9]|3[0-1]) (0?[1-9]|1[012])([: ][0-5]?[0-9])? ?[aApP]m (inferno|nuke|mirage|dust2|train|overpass|cache|\/)
```

Find a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ohf8C7/1)

There were far too many plus quantifiers scattered around, also you had duplicated some of the pattern needlessly in the middle.

With regex you need to be really careful about capturing things that you don't want to, make sure you think hard about edge cases, especially the desired negative ones.

**EDIT**

does this solve the multiple time parts requirement?

```
((mon|fri|sun)(day)?|tue(sday)?|wed(nesday)?|thu(rsday)?|sat(urday)?) (0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-([0-2]?[1-9]|3[0-1]) ((0?[1-9]|1[012])([: ][0-5]?[0-9])? ?[aApP]m )+(inferno|nuke|mirage|dust2|train|overpass|cache|\/)
```

demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ohf8C7/2)

**EDIT 2** (fix for 10 and 20 days)

```
((mon|fri|sun)(day)?|tue(sday)?|wed(nesday)?|thu(rsday)?|sat(urday)?) (0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-1]) ((0?[1-9]|1[012])([: ][0-5]?[0-9])? ?[aApP]m )+(inferno|nuke|mirage|dust2|train|overpass|cache|\/)
```

demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ohf8C7/3)

Comment: This is good, but it does not allow for multiple times or maps, my old one allowed for multiple maps and I was having issues with it trying to have multiple times but seems like it would always pass even if I had '13' as the second time, but if 13 was the first time it would fail, see my edit 4

Comment: No worries, similar to what i did in the demo link you need to show a list of matching and non matching string patterns that cover all your cases. Its very difficult to guess what is acceptable and what is not from a text description alone. You say you want to match multiple times which is do able but think about how you want this to look and parse.

Comment: This regex doesn't match days `10` & `20`

Comment: @Damo ill have to test that out but that's not his problem and not what my question was about anyways.